File encryption emits warning "CA5401: Do not use CreateEncryptor with non-default IV"
I'm trying to compress and encrypt a directory with a user-provided password using the following code:
using var aes = Aes.Create();
using var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foobar"), iterations: 100_000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
aes.Key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
aes.IV = pbkdf2.GetBytes(16);

var archivePath = Path.Combine(outputDir, "archive.tar.gz.aes");
using var archiveFileStream = new FileStream(archivePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(archiveFileStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
using var gzipStream = new GZipStream(cryptoStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
using var tarWriter = new TarWriter(gzipStream);

var files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(inputDir, "*", new EnumerationOptions { RecurseSubdirectories = true });
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var relativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(inputDir, file);
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file);
        var tarEntry = new PaxTarEntry(TarEntryType.RegularFile, relativePath)
        {
            DataStream = fileStream,
            ModificationTime = new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime
        };
        tarWriter.WriteEntry(tarEntry);
    }
    else
    {
        var tarEntry = new PaxTarEntry(TarEntryType.Directory, relativePath)
        {
            ModificationTime = new DirectoryInfo(file).LastWriteTime,
        };
        tarWriter.WriteEntry(tarEntry);
    }
}

But the line using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(archiveFileStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write); emits the warning [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca5401](Do not use CreateEncryptor with non-default IV) and I'm trying to figure out, if this is a false positive.
I think this warning suggests to use the default generated IV and store it in the encrypted file unencrypted. But does this really make it more secure? With the current implementation an intruder would still need to know the password to get the IV. With the suggested implementation the intruder could just read it from the file?!
Edit: I don't see my question answered by the linked duplicates. To be more specific: Is a random IV more secure than a password-derived one? And if so, why?

The IV does not need to be private. It's just a salt for the algorithm, to prevent duplicate messages/files frome being cracked. You must use a new IV for each encryption and store that with the encrypted data, otherwise the algorithm is not secure. See also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67071/is-it-safe-to-send-iv-in-plain-text-for-every-request

Also "With the current implementation an intruder would still need to know the password to get the IV." No, with the current implementation you couldn't even decrypt yourself as you've lost the IV.

@Charlieface Regarding your first comment: I'm having trouble to understand this. How is a random IV more secure than a password-derived one?
Regarding decryption: I actually can decrypt the file using the same password-derivation algorithm (see Rfc2898DeriveBytes in the code example)

@Chris_D_Turk Why do you want to create a password-derived IV when a random IV works just fine? Keep in mind that the IV doesn't need to be held secret. And how do you ensure that you generate a different IV from the same password-derivation algorithm each time you encrypt something?

@Progman because I don't have to store the IV then. I can just apply the same pbkdf2-algorithm to the supplied password when decrypting.

@Chris_D_Turk Then you might want to check https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41436/is-deriving-the-iv-from-the-password-secure

@Progman Thank you. So according to the linked answer, the .NET analyzer warning is actually a false positive in this case.

The default IV is generated using a secure crypto-random generator. It's not necessary to use a KDF to derive a new IV from it, it's mathematically unnecessary and only serves to slow you down. Just use a completely random IV and you're fine.
